# What engine are these fan blades from?

Tags: jet-engine, turbine, feature-identification, compressor, blade

I bought these from a metal scrapper and paid about $30.00 total figuring they're worth more than that in cool factor. Problem is they aren't nearly as cool if I can't figure out what engine (and hopefully aircraft) they come from. All I know is the compressor blade is titanium and the turbine blade has a high nickel content. So here I am hoping someone has an idea.

Also what might cause the wear patterns at the tip of the turbine blade? I appears like it may be cracked and then repaired. I cant imagine they would repair damage that extensive.

I cant find any pitting on the edges of either blade, leading me to believe neither blade was ever used, is my thinking correct?

**Turbine blade**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[source album](https://get.google.com/albumarchive/109887617374508242157/album/AF1QipM18DPBi8fBqeP-KvCwR1WKKiGqIpfgxmwDKCqC?authKey=CLmTptr6n7_xEw)

**Markings:**
Suction side

- 1475M85  (Possible 1475M35)
- BF P01 C (could potentially be a G at the end)

Pressure side

- FDW157B9

TE

- 1435P02
- 59669 (hard to see, could be something else)
- G12P

**Compressor blade**

[image]
[image]
[image]

[source album](https://get.google.com/albumarchive/109887617374508242157/album/AF1QipOaSkRgMOHO-zTf6l9ct3owVe5dy90ClnJm7cru?authKey=CJ76ptPp7IDGzQE)

**Markings**
Foot:

- B778503 FC
- MOJR

Comment: It might not have even come from an aircraft engine either.

Comment: It may help if you include some measurements.

Answer (score 13):

**Turbine Blade**
The turbine blade (part number 1475M35P01) is from the High Pressure Turbine (HPT) a [CFM56-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CFM_International_CFM56) according to [this ATSB](https://www.atsb.gov.au/media/24505/aair200405514_001.pdf) report on performance testing of the engine. The report contains several images of blades which look similar to your photos.

**Compressor blade**
A search on [locatory.com](https://www.locatory.com/search/B778503) for the part number (B778503) lists the description as `C-3` suggesting it could be a Stage 3 compressor blade. This would fit with the high aspect ratio of your blade.

Answer (score 8):

The part number on the turbine blade shows it comes from a CFM56-3 series (Boeing 737 classic). No hits on the compressor blade, but it looks similar to one from the same engine.